# how to use jarallax callback function?

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

I'm using the plugin of jarallax 
url: http://www.jarallax.com/

and want to figure out is there an easy way to fire callback in jarallax
below code seems not working.

```
    <script>
    init=function(){
     var jx=new Jarallax();
     jx.addAnimation('.bg',[{progress:'0%',top:'1px'},   
        {progress:'100%',top:'1700px',event:{complete:hideText}}]);

    }

     hideText = function() {
     alert('hide text function');
    }
    </script>
```